# Cannot access local variable in console when debugging reactjs in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When debugging js in browser, usually you put a breakpoint, and when the code hits there, you can access all local variables no matter your mouse hovers on it or you just type the variable name from the console (because you are in the execution scope)

But it seems to behave differently in react since I am able to see all local variables. However I cannot access them from the console or change its value from the console. Refer to the screenshot below.

So I can access `url` but cannot access `response` or `timeTakenByFetchApi`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `console.log` will be executed straight away, even though the promise has not returned anything.

Comment: I can access `url` but cannot access `response`